Moving average crossover using python
I am currently doing a personal stock market project.
I made a function that will give the date of the latest golden cross and death cross
def check_golden_cross(data):
    golden_crosses = []
    death_crosses = []
    for i in range(1, len(data.index)):
        if data["Moving_50"][i] >= data["Moving_200"][i] and data["Moving_50"][i-1] <= data["Moving_200"][i-1]:
            golden_crosses.append(data.index[i])
        elif data["Moving_50"][i] <= data["Moving_200"][i] and data["Moving_50"][i-1] >= data["Moving_200"][i-1]:
            death_crosses.append(data.index[i])
    return golden_crosses, death_crosses

can someone check this function for me please.
I calculate the moving average as follows:
def calculate_moving_average(data, period):
    data[f"Moving_{period}"] = data["Close"].rolling(period).mean()
    return data

please help me. I am in quiet trouble.

Please edit your question to include sufficient detail to answer your question.  Specifically, you incorrectly assume the users of this site will know what a 'Golden Cross" and a 'Death Cross' are, you have failed to provide any sample data which can be used to test your code, and finally, you haven't explained what error you encounter with this code.

Please share a sample of the data.

the data I use is the data I get from yahoo finance.

A golden cross is a situation where the long moving average(Moving_200) is below the short moving average(Moving_50). That means the stock price is about to rise.
A dead cross is a situation where the long moving average(Moving_200) is above the short moving average(Moving_50). That means the stock price is falling.
The problem I face is that the crossing points that I receive as an output is wrong at most of the times.

@JeshuwaBradley You write that they are wrong (crosses). What makes you say that? I made small changes but without huge impact and posted my answer. Look at it.

@SergedeGossondeVerennes I compared my plots with the yahoo finance and they were quite off.
Thank you for all the support. I'll check out your solution.

For future reference: Do not assume that people are at ease with financial data, especially using python. Most use R for this. Now, this is how you should approach this:
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ticker_symbol = 'AAPL'
ticker_data = yf.Ticker(ticker_symbol)
data = ticker_data.history(period='1d', start='2010-1-1', end='2021-1-1')


def calculate_moving_average(data, period):
    data[f"Moving_{period}"] = data["Close"].rolling(window=period, min_periods=period).mean()
    return data



def check_golden_cross(data):
    golden_crosses = []
    death_crosses = []
    if data['Moving_50'].isnull().any() or data['Moving_200'].isnull().any():
        print("Warning: NaN values found in moving averages. Check initial data points.")
    
    for i in range(1, len(data)):
        if not pd.isna(data["Moving_50"][i]) and not pd.isna(data["Moving_200"][i]):
            if data["Moving_50"][i] >= data["Moving_200"][i] and data["Moving_50"][i-1] < data["Moving_200"][i-1]:
                golden_crosses.append(data.index[i])
            elif data["Moving_50"][i] <= data["Moving_200"][i] and data["Moving_50"][i-1] > data["Moving_200"][i-1]:
                death_crosses.append(data.index[i])
    return golden_crosses, death_crosses


data = calculate_moving_average(data, 50)
data = calculate_moving_average(data, 200)
golden_crosses, death_crosses = check_golden_cross(data)
print("Golden Crosses:", golden_crosses)
print("Death Crosses:", death_crosses)


plt.figure(figsize=(14, 7))
plt.plot(data['Close'], label='Close Price')
plt.plot(data['Moving_50'], label='50-Day MA')
plt.plot(data['Moving_200'], label='200-Day MA')

if golden_crosses:
    plt.scatter(golden_crosses, data.loc[golden_crosses, 'Moving_50'], color='gold', label='Golden Cross', marker='^', s=100)
if death_crosses:
    plt.scatter(death_crosses, data.loc[death_crosses, 'Moving_50'], color='red', label='Death Cross', marker='v', s=100)

plt.title('Stock Price and Moving Averages')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Price')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

replace that with your own ticker. For this one:
Golden Crosses: [Timestamp('2013-09-10 00:00:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'), Timestamp('2016-08-30 00:00:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'), Timestamp('2019-05-06 00:00:00-0400', tz='America/New_York')]
Death Crosses: [Timestamp('2012-12-10 00:00:00-0500', tz='America/New_York'), Timestamp('2015-08-28 00:00:00-0400', tz='America/New_York'), Timestamp('2018-12-21 00:00:00-0500', tz='America/New_York')]

and visually:

